# how to replace xml elements with another xml elements in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

This is my two xml document.

This xml is stored in paraouterXml string.

```
<w:tbl>
 <w:tblPr>
 </w:tblPr>
 <w:tblGrid>
 </w:tblGrid>
</w:tbl>
```

This xml is stored in tblMetaInfo string.

```
<root>
 <w:tblPr>
  <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid" /> 
  <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto" /> 
  <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" /> 
  </w:tblPr>
 <w:tblGrid>
  <w:gridCol w:w="1947" /> 
  <w:gridCol w:w="1947" /> 
  </w:tblGrid>
</root>
```

So,here i want to replace paraouterXml's `<w:tblPr>,<w:tblGrid>` with tblMetaInfo's `<w:tblPr>,<w:tblGrid>` elements.

This is c# code...

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(table.OuterXml);
XmlNode newNode = xDoc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList tblPrNode = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("w:tblPr");
tblPrNode[0].RemoveAll();
XmlNodeList tblGridNode = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("w:tblGrid");
tblGridNode[0].RemoveAll();

XmlDocument xDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
xDoc1.LoadXml(tblMetaInfo);
XmlNode newNode1 = xDoc1.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList tblPrNode1 = xDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("w:tblPr");
XmlNodeList tblGridNode1 = xDoc1.GetElementsByTagName("w:tblGrid");

tblPrNode[0].ReplaceChild(tblPrNode1[0], tblPrNode[0]);
tblGridNode[0].ReplaceChild(tblGridNode1[0], tblGridNode[0]);
```

But it throwing some error...

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Error message is some like this "The newChild was created from a different document than the one that created this node"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*`ArgumentException`*: *The newChild was created from a different document than the one that created this node*.

[`public XmlNode ReplaceChild(XmlNode newChild, XmlNode oldChild)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.replacechild.aspx):

> If the **newChild** was created from **another document**, you can use [**`XmlDocument.ImportNode`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx) to import the node to the current document. The imported node can then be passed to the **`ReplaceChild`** method.